# Remove UIToolBar from the View

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a `UIbutton`, and when i click on that button i will show `UIToolBar` (located some where middle of the screen). (i coded this, and it works fine)

Now what i need to do is, when the user clicks anywhere in the screen, this toolbar should disappear. I know how to remove the `uitoolbar` off the screen as well `toolbar.hidden = YES;`

The thing i don't know is to remove the `uitoolbar` when the user clicks anywhere in the screen.

How can i code this ?

Comment: word of advice: u can out ur view after a button and set its method of action [toolbar remove from view] as so..

Comment: I guess you could look up on the UIGestureRecognizer class. For example the UITapGestureRecognizer can be attached to a view and call a method whenever a user taps on the view. See: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizers/GestureRecognizers.html

Answer (score 1):

Create a full screen view (to be used as container, set its backgroundColor to clearColor), add to this container view another full screen view (which can have a black background color and alpha 0.6) and then add your toolbar to the container view. In that second full screen view add a tapGestureRecognizer and in its selector, perform your animations, where you can do a cool fadeout. Use the completion block of the animation to remove/release anything you have to.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting nil for your UIToolbar. that is set the object value to nil for your toolbar.

Comment: What i want to do is, when the user clicks something on the screen (the view, a button, a text field)i need to remove the ToolBar. So how does your solution help me?